# How to use bunnyCDN to load images in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-image, bunnycdn

I'm working on a flutter app for a client and I've been stuck trying to load images from bunnyCDN and prior to this project I've never used bunnyCDN or any other CDN. I've done research and every necessary step to figure out how to go about it but still to no avail. I need help on how to load, download and upload from bunnyCDN in flutter app.

Thanks in advance.